# Run command using SSH and don't close it when session is closed

Tags: python-3.x

I want to be able to run processes on vm's using ssh. I've tried using paramiko but I have one issue that after executing a command (in this case for example running notepad.exe), when the session closes the notepad closes as well.

How do I make it so the process will continue running even if the session is closed ?

Btw, if you have a better suggestion than paramiko its also fine.

```
def runfile(ip):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(ip, username="Administrator", password="Password1")
    print("runnning command")
    s = ssh.exec_command(r"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe", timeout=3)
    print(s)
```